# Framework for reinforcement learning for games

Tags: games, reinforcement-learning

[I hope this is the correct place to post - if not, please feel free to migrate the question to another site].

I would like to build a computer program that will play games effectively, and I want to use reinforcement learning techniques, namely, let two copies of the program play against each other, and use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal-difference_learning for learning an optimal strategy.

Before I start coding - is there an existing framework for such tasks? Preferrably in Java, but not necessarily.

I found some Java frameworks for reinforcement learning, but they are not geared towards games.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @ErelSegaHalevi. I'm wondering if CV is the right place to ask your question. Are you primarily wondering about the machine-learning aspects of this? (IE, how to adapt RL algorithms in this way.) Or, are you just wondering about how to code it / looking for helpful java libraries? If it's the former, CV is a good choice, if the latter, this Q would be better asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). *Please don't cross-post, though* (SE strongly discourages this. If you need your Q migrated faster, flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @gung unfortunately, SO labels such questions as not constructive and closes them mercilessly, meanwhile here on stats.SE we are more liberal. So we have to close it, too ? As not constructive ?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi if you can model your problem in the standard terms of RL, you can use any rl framework, it doesn't need to be tailored explicitly for games. Additionally, to add more value to the question, you could add the resources you have found so far.

Comment: @steffen you are probably right, but I don't have much experience with reinforcement learning, so having a framework that uses the more common terms "game", "players" etc. will be easier to use.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi there is not much required :). I really recommend the book of [Sutton and Barto (available for free)](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html), start reading and since you are a computer scientist your ability to see things on a higher abstraction level will soon kick in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some frameworks under the [RLAI](http://incompleteideas.net/rlai.cs.ualberta.ca/RLAI/rlai.html) site.

I don't know of any which are already set up with game-play environments, but you might find some good ideas and C source code here,
"[Reinforcement learning In board Games](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3awvqgxapPdyUJ%3aciteseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi%3D10.1.1.4.7712%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf+reinforcement+learning+games&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShu99AMomWoXTIVSIE431_3DcqCIY8RahQwRmbrvh8HJn-KeSxJZ1rEyeISlt3LVEU6HsjtNsL_UeL5gnNccNOeHiNjUF26lzQUwK5rSz0p-_iUe6msSGRNSouKBzoAHQSntvGf&sig=AHIEtbTP5EuJRehTSPt5Ob87Qi15pST4Dg)," Imran Gohry *

This is a table I copied from [AI Application Programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584504218), 2nd edition, M. Tim Jones (p. 226), to give an idea of some historical applications.

Table 9.2 Interesting Historical Uses of RL

```
 Application              Algorithm Used 

 Backgammon (TD-Gammon)    TD(lambda) with a Neural Network 
 Blackjack                 TD(lambda)
 Scheduling problems       TD(lambda), Time Delay Neural Networks
 Robotic Control Systems   SARSA, TD(Lambda), Q Learning 
 Tic-Tac-Toe               Q Learning 
 Elevator Control          Q Learning 
 Chess/Checkers            Q Learning
```

Good Luck.

- If you have trouble sourcing, you can select html view or just do a google search for the paper and title.

Comment: RLAI looks a bit old - some links don't work, some links point to old frameworks ("Reinforcement learning toolbox" was last updated 2006, PIQLE - 2007, Connectionst Q-Learning - 2008). It could really help to know which of them really works, before I go through the task of installing them...

Comment: Well, although it is old, PIQLE still works, and has just what I needed - a simple framework for defining two-player games and learning strategies. Thank you!